# How to reweight to sustain covariate distributions across different samples with Python?

Tags: python, distribution, matching, sample, weighting

I have two independent samples, which vary in their numbers of observations and in the distributions of two variables (Let's assume there are no more variables). I want to sustain the distributions existing in set 1 for both variables in set 2 as well. Thus, I need to find an appropriate way to reweight observations in sample 2 so that distrbutions of the two variables in each sample are quite similar or even match. In other words, I want to produce two balanced sets in the two variables based on the distributions of set 1.

If I am not completely wrong, my question is about post-stratification and reweighting techniques in python.

Has anybody links to already published python code doing exactly that or an idea how to match distributions of multiple variables in two samples using python?

Comment: Wrong place to ask, here people usually deal with code, not methodology. Try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com